FastAPI Simple HTTP Basic Auth not Working when running in Docker container
I followed this guide to set Simple HTTP Basic Auth and it works. I dockerized the application and all of a sudden the Auth pop-up which ask for user name and password does not show up anymore. I am running the application identically (i.e the same as I ran it locally but with docker)
I dont know what running it in docker would somehow remove that functionality. Is there something I am missing or not understanding? Meaning what would I have to change for this to be resolved.
I different configurations of Simple HTTP Basic Auth in FastApi. I also tried to ask AI chatbots
# HTTPBasic Logic
import secrets
from typing import Annotated

from fastapi import Depends, FastAPI, HTTPException, status
from fastapi.security import HTTPBasic, HTTPBasicCredentials


security = HTTPBasic()


def get_current_username(
    credentials: Annotated[HTTPBasicCredentials, Depends(security)],
):
    current_username_bytes = credentials.username.encode("utf8")
    correct_username_bytes = b"stanleyjobson"
    is_correct_username = secrets.compare_digest(
        current_username_bytes, correct_username_bytes
    )
    current_password_bytes = credentials.password.encode("utf8")
    correct_password_bytes = b"swordfish"
    is_correct_password = secrets.compare_digest(
        current_password_bytes, correct_password_bytes
    )
    if not (is_correct_username and is_correct_password):
        raise HTTPException(
            status_code=status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED,
            detail="Incorrect username or password",
            headers={"WWW-Authenticate": "Basic"},
        )
    return credentials.username

app = FastAPI(dependencies=[Depends(get_current_username)])


# Docker 
FROM python:3.11
Create a user and group for the application
RUN addgroup --system app && adduser --system --group app

ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE=1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1
ENV ENVIRONMENT=prod
ENV TESTING=0

RUN apt-get update -y && apt-get install -y \
    python3-dev \
    python3-venv \
    graphviz \
    libgraphviz-dev \
    pkg-config

WORKDIR /app/
UN python3 -m venv /app/venv

# Activate virtual environment and install requirements
RUN . /app/venv/bin/activate && pip install -r requirements.txt

# Set environment variable to ensure Python packages execute from the virtualenv
ENV PATH="/app/venv/bin:$PATH"

EXPOSE 8000

uvicorn --reload --host "127.0.0.1"  "main:app" --log-config=log_conf.yaml


By any chance are you accessing the dockerized application on the same http://host:port as your local test environment? If yes, your browser probably saved the authentication data you provided during testing and thus logs you in automatically with those saved credentials. Try clearing your browser cache, or using a different browser/browser profile
